# Change language of the user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization

I have model User with an attribute language. When user visit site, locale should be automatically checked by the Accept Header's language of the browser and this locale should be set to the language attribute. I use gem 'http_accept_language'. I also have button "change language", which should change language of the user. Now language of the site changes, but it is saved only in cookies and the language attribute is equal nil..

application_controller.rb (automatically check Accept Header's language and set it to the user's language)

```
**class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :require_login, :set_locale
  include HttpAcceptLanguage::AutoLocale

  private

  def not_authenticated
    redirect_to login_path, alert: "Пожалуйста, войдите на сайт"
  end

  def set_locale
    if params[:locale].present?
      locale = params[:locale].to_sym
      cookies.permanent[:locale] = I18n.available_locales.include?(locale) ? locale : nil
      current_user.update(language: cookies.permanent[:locale])
    end

    I18n.locale = cookies[:locale]
   end
end**
```

settings_controller.rb (change language)

```
    class SettingsController < ApplicationController
      def change_locale
        l = params[:locale].to_s.strip.to_sym
        l = I18n.default_locale unless I18n.available_locales.include?(l)
        u = current_user
        u.update(language: I18n.locale.to_s)
        redirect_to request.referer || root_url
      end
    end
```